# Apps disappeared after unlocking, backup and restore of my iPhone

Tags: iphone, backup, restore

I unlocked my iPhone yesterday and backed up and restored my data using iTunes, however my apps did not come back onto my phone when I restored from backup.

How do I find them on my computer in my backup, and restore them to my iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you didn't transfer your purchased apps to iTunes before you restored the phone. Under normal circumstances you would have gotten a warning message about this. Look under Applications in iTunes, check the iPhone tab and see if your apps are listed there, if not they are not backed up. If you have connected your iTunes software with your iPhone Apple account the apps should sync automatically.

Only way to get them back otherwise is to go to Appstore and download them again. Easiest way is to enter Appstore, go to the Update tab and press Purchases/Not on iPhone. (Using the same Apple-account you won't have to pay for your purchased apps again.)

Comment: that works for me,, i did not backup my apps before i delete my content.
But now i can see my apps from app store purchases section.
thanks dude

Answer (score 1):

I thought I had this problem but in fact I just needed to let iTunes sync the iPhone after the backup had initially restored and I'd registered the new handset on the phone network. The phone appeared fine and I had many apps - but not all. After letting it sync they all returned :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the apps are not automatically uploaded to the phone after a recovery.

iTunes normally stores the apps on your computer,except if you manually moved or removed them.

so what you can do after a restore is:

1. Open iTunes
2. Connect your phone
3. Go to "Your Phone> Apps"
4. Click on the "install/uninstall/suppress" button of one of the app (this will make the "Apply" button appear in the lower-right corner)
5. Click on the Apply button.
6. Wait, wait, wait... the more you have apps, the longer it is to process

(The buttons name may vary as I translated their name from my iTunes install which is in french).

While the apps are being uploaded, you should see their greyed icons with a progress bar on the phone.